# How do I display 16bit grayscale image into picturebox?

Tags: c#, image

I have an ushort list that contains image data , and I want to display this image in a picture box so firstly I load it into a `MemoryStream` then I use `FromStream` method in `image` class to load it into `pictureBox` :

```
.
.
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pixels24.ToArray()); //pixels24 is ushort[]
this.DicomImage.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
.
.
```

if i run this  error shows up :

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.IO.MemoryStream.MemoryStream(int)' has some invalid arguments

I knew that `MemoryStream` can't take ushort array as input it takes byte[] instead ...
So how do I put image represented in ushort array to picturebox ?

Comment: It all depends on what the data in your `ushort[]` actually is. The `FromStream()` method assumes an actual bitmap file format. You can't just pass arbitrary bytes to it. Your question is too broad, because you've provided practically no real context.

Comment: afaik 16bpp is __defined__ but not __not supported__ so you would have to __scale down__ the ushort to bytes. Or is DicomImage from a library that should help? If it is just a PBox this can't work..You need to give much more info!! Also: Do consider Peter's comment: How could the Image.FromStream decide if the array contains a 100x200 or a 200x100 or a 50x400 pixel (etc etc) image??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `ushort` values are between 0 and 255,

```
checked
{
    ushort[] vals = pixels24.ToArray();
    var imgbytes = (from val in vals
                 select (byte)val).ToArray();

    // Your Code
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgbytes); 
    this.DicomImage.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

The `checked` block is used to throw an exception during an overflow when `ushort` value is more than 255.

Answer (score 0):

Your desire is a little weird because according to the references the range of `ushort` is greater than the `Byte` so if you even convert the `ushort` array to the `byte` array you may confront with the **data loss issue** or **system.overflowexception**. If you can deal with the problem and do some code for handling the exception you can simply convert the array.

**byte.MinValue=0/byte.MaxValue = 255**

**ushort.MinValue=0/ushort.MaxValue=65535**

This is a simple example

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
 {
    try
     {
      bytPixle24[i] = Convert.ToByte(pixel24[i]);
     }
    catch (System.OverflowException ex)
     {
       // ...
     }
 }
```